# Restricting character input on iPhone UITextField

Tags: iphone, objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [allow only alphanumeric characters for a UITextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7541803/allow-only-alphanumeric-characters-for-a-uitextfield)

Is there a way of only letting the user input letters and numbers, no symbols, via the keyboard into a UITextField?

Comment: Daidai, change your UITextField keyboard type to "Name Phone Pad". It will only show Characters or Numbers to input.

Comment: @H e m a n g - thanks it works but the UX is not normal.

Answer (score 10):

Use this delegate methods.. as It works for me..

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    if(textField == YOUR TEXT FIELD)
    {
        NSCharacterSet *invalidCharSet = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789"] invertedSet];
        NSString *filtered = [[string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:invalidCharSet] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
        return [string isEqualToString:filtered];
    }
    else
        return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
- (BOOL) textField: (UITextField *)theTextField shouldChangeCharactersInRange: (NSRange)range replacementString: (NSString *)string {    
  //return yes or no after comparing the characters
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
 {
   NSCharacterSet *nonNumberSet = [[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] invertedSet];
        if(![string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:nonNumberSet].length)
        {
            return NO;
        }
   return YES;
```

}

Comment: This only works for decimals, no?

Comment: Yes this code makes sure that the user does not enter any symbol as well as any character. You can modify it according to ur requirement by adding '||' int the if statement and comparing characters.

Comment: looks like you can use NSCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet

Comment: this code disables the backspace touches for uitextview (at least for my app). a better solution is using [string rangeOfCharacterFromSet:nonNumberSet].location != NSNotFound in the if statement.