# UITextField - Prevent user from typing non-standard characters (like Emoticons)

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uikeyboard, nscharacterset

My app creates and stores `EKEvents` into the standard Calendar database, however, I've found that if I use an emoticon as the "notes" for an event, it causes a crash when trying to read the event out of the Calendar.

I don't *want* or *need* the use of emoticons in the `event.notes`. I just happened to be testing and was kind of shocked when it let me save the event. (The emoticons even show up in the Calendar itself)

So I think my problem can be solved one of 2 way, neither of which I've been able to figure out.

**1) Can I disable or hide the custom keyboard button?** <--I'd prefer this solution

[image]

**2) If not, how do I create a character set that includes all of the possible characters in all of the standard keyboards to check against when making sure the user does not type an emoticon?**

I've tried using some of the standard character sets to check against, like `alphanumericCharacterSet`, but using that, I can't type in spaces.

Here's the code I'm using so far, to check against the character the user is typing:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)theTextField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    if (string.length == 0) {
        return YES;
    }

    NSCharacterSet *myCharSet = [NSCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet];
    for (int i = 0; i < [string length]; i++) {
        unichar c = [string characterAtIndex:i];
        if ([myCharSet characterIsMember:c]) {
            return YES;
        }
    }

    UIAlertView *av = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Invalid Input" message:@"Oops! You can't use that character." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [av show];
    return NO;
}
```

***EDIT: Clarification on the error***

There is no error, only a crash. 
My app saves calendar events, and displays them in a list to the user. 
The user can then mark the event as "Paid" or "Unpaid" at which time I append a string to the `.notes` property of the event " - Paid". This is so when I reload the table, if the event is paid, it displays a specific icon to the user.
The crash happens when the saved even has an emoticon as the `.notes` property, and I try to append the `.notes`.

Comment: What's the error you get if there is an Emoji character in the event notes? Your best solution may be to solve that problem.

Comment: @rmaddy its not an error, he simply dont want it, that clean text will be poluted with funny icons

Comment: @rmaddy, see my edit. I explained exactly what's happening.

Comment: @jhilgert00 No, that doesn't answer my question. What is the actual error shown in the crash? Have you looked at the stack trace? You may have a simple bug that can be fixed.

Comment: ok, hang on. Gotta get that for you....

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7541803/allow-only-alphanumeric-characters-for-a-uitextfield

Comment: Well, thanks for your help everyone. Turned out to be an eventStore issue. I'll mark Tim's answer since he did answer the question though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can combine `NSCharacterSet`s using a union to add more allowable characters:

```
    NSMutableCharacterSet *myCharSet = [[NSCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet] mutableCopy];
    [myCharSet formUnionWithCharacterSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet];
```

Here is the list of available character sets to choose from:

```
controlCharacterSet
whitespaceCharacterSet
whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet
decimalDigitCharacterSet
letterCharacterSet
lowercaseLetterCharacterSet
uppercaseLetterCharacterSet
nonBaseCharacterSet
alphanumericCharacterSet
decomposableCharacterSet
illegalCharacterSet
punctuationCharacterSet
capitalizedLetterCharacterSet
symbolCharacterSet
newlineCharacterSet
```

Also, your code is checking to make sure **any** character is not outside the set; I think your intention is to check that **all** characters are not outside the set.  (This only applies when the user enters more than one character at once - think copy and paste).

Consider adjusting your loop to look more like this:

```
NSCharacterSet *myCharSet = [NSCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet];
for (int i = 0; i < [string length]; i++) {
    unichar c = [string characterAtIndex:i];
    if ([myCharSet characterIsMember:c] == NO) {
        // add your user alert here
        return NO;
    }
}
```

This way your loop won't simply exit on the first good character it finds; instead, it will exit on the first bad character.

Comment: It's easier to use just `-rangeOfCharacterFromSet:` than iterating `unichar`s yourself.