# Check if String contains alphanumeric

Tags: ios, nsstring, alphanumeric

I want to check the string if it contains alphanumeric only.(Both letters and number only).
I tried using `NSCharacterSet *strCharSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890"];`

I also tried this `NSString *string = @"[^a-zA-Z0-9]";` = no luck

but it only checks if the string does not contain any characters or it contains only this characters. I need to required the user to put both letters and numbers.

-update
I have a textfield for password. I need the user to input both letters and password. But I can't check if the textfield contains BOTH letters and numbers. By using the code above, it only checks if the textfield's text contains only alphanumeric.

Comment: try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7541803/allow-only-alphanumeric-characters-for-a-uitextfield

Comment: it works the same, it just allow user to input alphanumeric, what i want is to required the user to input numbers and letter.

Comment: You haven't really shown enough code to know HOW you are checking or what you are trying to accomplish . Also note, your approach will be limited to English and fail with most other languages.

Comment: Show all the code you're using. If you want 2 different checks, don't combine the data that you use to make those checks...

Comment: Try this [String rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet]].location != NSNotFound && [String rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[NSCharacterSet letterCharacterSet]].location != NSNotFound

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You just need to make your checks for numbers and letters separate.

```
BOOL containsLetter = NSNotFound != [input rangeOfCharacterFromSet:NSCharacterSet.letterCharacterSet].location;
BOOL containsNumber = NSNotFound != [input rangeOfCharacterFromSet:NSCharacterSet.decimalDigitCharacterSet].location;

NSLog(@"Contains letter: %d\n Contains number: %d", containsLetter, containsNumber);
```