# Ipad numbers only in one of two text fields

Tags: ios, ipad

I am working with an Ipad. My view controller has two text fields. One will accept regular text. The second I want only numbers. As usual I set the keyboard type on the second text field to the decimal keyboard.

I would like to restrict the second field to only numbers. I have found several possible solutions on this site but none seem to work. I don't seem to be able to select the second text field for the restrictions I'm looking for.

Any suggestions would help this new programmer. THX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must adopt the `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol and implement the following method in your related `UIViewController`.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{

 //place your checking code here...

}
```

[Method reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextFieldDelegate/textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:)

[SO post related to your question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7541803/allow-only-alphanumeric-characters-for-a-uitextfield)

Comment: Thanks. I had set the delegate and set the delegate to the text field in the view did load. Problem solved. THX